# Determine document class before running tex

Tags: document-classes

Is it possible to know what document class is required before running `pdflatex my_file.tex` or `xelatex my_file.tex`?

I've built a dynamic latex generator and depending on the required class name I'll download it from a server instead of storing all the available classes locally.

For instance, if I have this tex file:

```
\documentclass{my-fancy-class}
    [Content here]
\end{document}
```

I want to know that I need to download `my-fancy-class.cls` from my server.

If this is possible, will it be slow (compared to generating the pdf)?

Similarly, is it possible to determine what images will be required?

Comment: You can use `kpsewhich` to look-up whether the class file is stored on your system: `kpsewhich my-fancy-class.cls`

Comment: You could use grep for determining the argument to `\documentclass`

Comment: what do you mean by "possible" it is of course trivial in easy cases (just use grep or similar to look for the document class) but arbitrarily hard if tex macros are involved) fetching the class from a server might take longer than generating the pdf, or not, depending on the connection to theserver.

Comment: Or make a first run with `pdflatex -interaction=batchmode -draftmode` and scan the resulting `log` for ``! LaTeX Error: File `….cls' not found.`` You can use the almost same for searching for packages.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try these out. It may be easier to just save all the class files locally somehow. The trouble is I'm using Heroku and they don't support permanent file systems...